# Set position of image relative to other object

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble to position a small image with it's center on the upper right corner of another box element. It should look something like that:
[image: sketch goal]

However I couldn't find a solution how to position it correctly outside of the container.
The closest I could get is with:

`<img src="cert.svg" style="position: absolute; height: 100px; top: 5vh; left: 30vw;">`

But that's only a very rough solution, as it can break for example on different zoom factors and when resizing the browser window.
Any ideas howto achieve this are appreciated!

---

**Full code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
  .codebox {    
    width: 30vw;
    padding: 15px;
    font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #111927;
  }

  .codetitle {
    width: 30vw;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 10px;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    background-color: coral;
  }
</style>

<body>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <img src="image.png" style="position: absolute; height: 100px; top: 5vh; left: 30vw;">
    <div class="codetitle">Sourcecode:</div>
    <div class="codebox" style="font-family: Courier, monospace;">
        <p><code>
            This is some source code.
        </code></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the above result, you could add `position: relative;` to codebox's style.
Then, place the image inside the codebox and place it at `top: 0; right: 0;`.

If you need it to go more up, you could use a negative value for `top` attribute.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
  .codebox {    
    width: 30vw;
    padding: 15px;
    font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #111927;
  }

  .codetitle {
    width: 30vw;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 10px;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    background-color: coral;
  }
</style>

<body>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <div class="codetitle">Sourcecode:</div>
    <div class="codebox" style="font-family: Courier, monospace; position: relative;">
        <img src="image.png" style="position: absolute; height: 100px; top: -20px; right: 0;">
        <p><code>
            This is some source code.
        </code></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't think of putting the <img>-tag that way.

Answer (score 2):

This answer uses custom properties to make it more understandable.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.box{
  --box-height: min(40vh, 20rem);
  --box-width: min(50vw, 40rem);
  width: var(--box-width);
  height: var(--box-height);
  background-color: silver;
}

.ribbon{
  --image-size: 5rem;
  --image-placement: calc(-1 * var(--image-size) / 2);
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  
  display: flex;
  place-content: center;
}

.ribbon::before{
  content: "";
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150");
  background-position: center;
  width: var(--image-size);
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--image-placement);
  right: var(--image-placement);
}
```

```html
<section class="box">
  <header class="ribbon">Header</header>
</section>
```

Comment: And also thank you very much for the in-depth explanation! Really helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}

.card .header {
  height: 10%;
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: .5;
}

.card .content {
  height: 90%;
  background-color: green;
  opacity: .5;
}

.card .img-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10%;
  right: -10%;
  height: 30%;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: pink;
  transform: skewX(-30deg);
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="img-box"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

[The Output Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhZPe.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    *{
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .main{
        position: relative;
    }

    .code{
        width: 30vw;
    }

    .myImage{
        position: absolute;
        top:-30px;
        right:-30px;
        width: 70px;
    }

    .codebox {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px;
        font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #111927;
    }

    .codetitle {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 5px 20px 5px 10px;
        font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
        background-color: coral;
        margin: 0;
    }

</style>

<body>
<p style="width:100%;margin: 20px 0;">Lorem ipsum</p>
<div class="main">
    <div class="code">
        <h1 class="codetitle">Sourcecode:</h1>
        <div class="codebox">
            <p><code>
                This is some source code.
            </code></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img class="myImage" src="image.png">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).